# To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, font-awesome

I created a new project with angular-cli (`ng new my-project-name`)

When I run `npm run test` it run without any failures.

I added font-awsome module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome) in my project to display font icons.

In my html file added `<fa name="bars"></fa>` tag and got output as expected. If I run `npm run test` again it is ending with 3 failures, all of them are targeting `fa` tag.

Here is sample failure report

```
'fa' is not a known element:
        1. If 'fa' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
        <div style="text-align:center">          [ERROR ->]<fa name="bars"></fa>
          <h1>            Welcome to {{title}}!
        "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@2:2        Error: Template parse errors:
            at syntaxError home/harsha/Documents/Projects/testProject/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:466:22)
```

I tried some fixes like adding `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`, `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in `app.module.ts` file.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
})`
```

But nothing worked.

Comment: Have you imported module in NgModule?
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
imports: [
    //...
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ]

Comment: yeah I imported it, followed 'angular-font-awesome' documentation and I dont have any issues in displaying icons, it is failing in test cases only

Answer (score 29):

In your test spec file it needs to be set up like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ yourcomponent ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Notice the schemas property in the TestBed.configureTestingModule method.  After setting the schemas property your tests should run without error as before you added Font Awsome component.

Comment: you have to add it to the import too: import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

Answer (score 25):

I resolved this issue creating a custom component called SampleComponent(sample.ts), which I want to use in welcome.html comes under common module file for all custom component in ionic project by name **components.module.ts** which looks as follows:

```
import { NgModule,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { SampleComponent } from './sample/sample';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [SampleComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [SampleComponent],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
      ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

In **welcome.module.ts** where I want to use my **sample.component.ts** I imported **components.module.ts** which look like following

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { WelcomePage } from './welcome';
import { ComponentsModule } from "../../components/components.module";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    WelcomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(WelcomePage),
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    WelcomePage
  ]
})
export class WelcomePageModule { }
```

**welcome.html** where I used my custom component (SampleComponent)

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <div class="splash-bg"></div>
  <div class="splash-info">
    <div class="splash-logo"></div>
    <div class="splash-intro">
      {{ 'WELCOME_INTRO' | translate }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div padding>
    <p>`enter code here`
      <sample>loading...</sample>
    </p>
    <button ion-button block (click)="signup()">{{ 'SIGNUP' | translate }}</button>
    <button ion-button block (click)="login()" class="login">{{ 'LOGIN' | translate }}</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error while developing dynamic component approach into my project, which was described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular). In my case the error was generated by passing svg tags through `DynamicComponent`. Adding `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` into `@NgModule` of in this component helped:

```
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit, Input, NgModule, NgModuleFactory, Compiler, SimpleChanges, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../../../../../../../../shared.module';

@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic',
    template: `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="dynamicComponent; ngModuleFactory: dynamicModule;"></ng-container>`
})

export class DynamicComponent {
    dynamicComponent: any;
    dynamicModule: NgModuleFactory<any>;

    @Input('html') html: string;

    constructor(private compiler: Compiler) {}

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes['html'] && !changes['html'].isFirstChange()) {
            this.dynamicComponent = this.createNewComponent(this.html);
            this.dynamicModule = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(this.createComponentModule(this.dynamicComponent));
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dynamicComponent = this.createNewComponent(this.html);
        this.dynamicModule = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(this.createComponentModule(this.dynamicComponent));
    }

    protected createComponentModule(componentType: any) {
        @NgModule({
            imports: [SharedModule],
            declarations: [componentType],
            entryComponents: [componentType],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        })
        class RuntimeComponentModule {}
        // a module for just this Type
        return RuntimeComponentModule;
    }

    protected createNewComponent(template: string) {

        @Component({
            selector: 'dynamic-component',
            template: template ? template : '<div></div>'
        })
        class MyDynamicComponent {
            //metods passed via dynamic component to svg
            testMe() {
                alert('test passed!');
            }
        }

        return MyDynamicComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect. I ran into this same problem with dynamic components and having to support old html elements that have since been deprecated in HTML5. Thanks mpro!

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` for such simple scenario, if the component works fine and the tests just miss the `fa` component, then you need to add `AngularFontAwesomeModule` also to your TestBed imports.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you are adding this NgModule property to a feature module, you also have to add it to your root NgModule.  Or at least I had to.